# Which tool can I use to generate a .jshintrc file with default options?

Tags: jshint

I've being using JSLint for some time now and recently found JSHint. Reading the [docs](http://jshint.com/docs/) I learned that it can be configured using a .jshintrc file but I could not found if it's possible to generate this file using the [CLI](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/).

Is there a flag in the CLI to generate such file (preferably with all the options set) or another tool that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really going to answer your question but I found the JShint I use on some article about code style guides, in a free HTML eBook [SpeakingJS - Style guide](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch26.html#_existing_style_guides).

They talk about Google's guideline, AirBNB's guideline, jQuery's guideline, and others, most of the time those links provide its a ready to use jshint file ... may be this could help you :).

If you want to generate your own JSHint, I don't know if you are familiar with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) but this project is exactly what you re looking for : https://github.com/losingkeys/generator-jshint

After generating it, any text editor can be used to edit such a simple file.

Comment: Thank for contributting. I know i can edit the file using any text editor but writting something like "jshint generate" and then edit the different configurations will save a lot of time than having to check the docs for the different configurations in case you misspelled any of them.

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with Yeoman, but looks like this project is exactly what you need : https://github.com/losingkeys/generator-jshint I will update my answer to include this ressource.

Comment: Yes!!! That is exactly what I need. Please edit and improve your answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just found about it too so was interesting spending time on it, thanks and good luck with it :D

Comment: Warning: The generator suggested by @sebastienbarbier **doesn't work** (crashes mid-setup), and it's been abandoned for at least two years.